# Handle type of video uploaded in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I am new to javascript.
My javascript code allows me to upload a video.
The type of video accepted is only of type mp4.
I am trying to make it allow uploading videos of type avi 
Can you tell me how to modify it or what to look at to be able to let it upload type avi
Thanx

```
(function localFileVideoPlayerInit(win) {
var URL = win.URL || win.webkitURL,
    displayMessage = (function displayMessageInit() {
        var node = document.querySelector('#message');

        return function displayMessage(message, isError) {
            node.innerHTML = message;
            node.className = isError ? 'error' : 'info';
        };
    }()),
    playSelectedFile = function playSelectedFileInit(event) {
        var file = this.files[0];

        var type = file.type;

        var videoNode = document.querySelector('video');

        var canPlay = videoNode.canPlayType(type);

        canPlay = (canPlay === '' ? 'no' : canPlay);

        var message = 'Can play type "' + type + '": ' + canPlay;

        var isError = canPlay === 'no';

        displayMessage(message, isError);

        if (isError) {
            return;
        }

        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

        videoNode.src = fileURL;
    },
    inputNode = document.querySelector('input');

    if (!URL) {
    displayMessage('Your browser is not ' + 
       '<a href="http://caniuse.com/bloburls">supported</a>!', true);

    return;
    }                

    inputNode.addEventListener('change', playSelectedFile, false);
}(window));
```

This is the html part where the video is being handled.

```
    <div id="message"></div>
    <div id="message1">
    <input id="iii" type="file" accept="video/*"/>
    <video id="vv" controls autoplay></video>
    </div>
```

Comment: Seems to me that the allowed file type might be set in the html, please add the HTML code. Another possibility is that the JS is sending to a backend which does the check.

Comment: @JamieHutber html is added

Comment: you can still upload avi, but the browsers don't support it